# HTML horizontal scrolling is not working properly

Tags: html, css

I have a table in my HTML and it is wider than the window. So I created it to scroll horizontally. I created a link to move to a specific `<th>` in the table by horizontally scrolling when click on the link.

```
<a href="#nic_name">Goto Nic</a>
```

When I click on the link, it is moving to the specific `<th>` by scrolling horizontally and also by scrolling down vertically. So, I can't see the `<Div>` above the table. Can I stop this vertical scrolling?

**Update:**

This is a demo most likely what I have. I need to move to points while seeing the upper "AAAAAA" part. That means without scrolling vertically.

http://jsfiddle.net/34r76ag8/

Comment: If I recall correctly, the anchor tag will bring the anchor point into view when you click on it - so the necessary scrolling will be done (both vertically and horizontally)  - I am not sure if you can prevent it automatically unless A) you point your anchor destination within the height of the browser at the beginning 
 - Or B) use javascript

Comment: Also, could you add a [mcve] to your question to know if there are other options on how to help?

Comment: Welcome to `Stack Overflow`, it's better to put some of your codes. but if you wanna prevent vertical scrolling you should use `JavaScript`.

Comment: See this JSfiddle... I need to move to a particular span while seeing the upper AAAA part.

http://jsfiddle.net/34r76ag8/

Comment: This may be helpful: [Horizontal scroll to anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913135/horizontal-scroll-to-anchor)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this (in your demo):

```
.blue{
  position: relative;
  left: 1500px;
  margin-top: -150px;
  padding-top: 150px
}
```